# Send a list of objects one at time in reactive way

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm receiving a request through a rest controller method with an object that I'm then passing to a method in the service layer.

The object in this request contains a list as follows:

```
public class BalanceAlertServiceRequestData extends AlertServiceRequestData {
    
   private List<BalanceAlertAttribute> balanceAlertList;
```

Instead of just sending the whole list over at once in a Mono, as I've done in other methods, in this case, there is a requirement to send one list item at a time.

Here's the method with questions in the code comment:

```
public Mono<AlertServiceResponse> sendBalanceAlertDataToPrepaid(BalanceAlertServiceRequest cartasRequest) {
    return Mono.just(cartasRequest.getBalanceAlertServiceRequestData().getBalanceAlertList())
        // what goes here to read off each element, transform it, and then send it of as a single element in a Mono?
        // Would it be something like "doOnEach(mapBalanceAlertServiceRequestToBalanceChangeAlertResponse)?"
        .flatMap(prepaidClient::sendBalanceAlertData)
        .thenReturn(cartaResponse(cartasRequest.getServiceRequestId()));
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the data in cartasRequest.getBalanceAlertServiceRequestData().getBalanceAlertList() Do you use R2DBC?

Comment: It is arriving in JSON request data through a Rest controller, so Jackson is deserializing this data and populating the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected way to do that is to actually use the `fromIterable` method and provide your `List`:

```java
 return Flux.fromIterable(cartasRequest.getBalanceAlertServiceRequestData().getBalanceAlertList())
                .flatMap(prepaidClient::sendBalanceAlertData)
// convert to Mono again
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this!
I do now have some more questions though...
So does this return a Mono of BalanceAlertAttribute? If I'm reading the docs correctly, this returns a Flux? Or does it return a Flux with a single element?

Comment: `Flux.fromIterable` creates a `Flux` of `BalanceAlertAttribute`. The `sendBalanceAlertData` method will be invoked for each item of the `Flux`.

Comment: Ah ok, awesome! Thank you for clarifying! :)